# Install SQL Server 2012 SP4

Tags: sql-server-2012

Can I install SQL Server 2012 SP4 on a SQL Server 2012 running SP2? Do I need to install SP3 first?

Thanks,
XAC

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to install SP3 before installing SP4 of SQL Server 2012.  According to the documentation for [Announcing SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/announcing-sql-server-2012-service-pack-4/):

> SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 4 will include

- All fixes and CUs for SQL 2012 up to and including SQL Server 2012 SP3 CU9.